# How do I recover my files using backups in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, files, backup

I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 and then made a new profile and whatnot. Of course I wanted my files back, so I decided to run backups.

I have searched but I have literally no idea how to use backups to restore files, especially in a different system. I'd assume one point of backups is to be able to download your files on other systems.

If anyone can help me with this I would be incredibly grateful. I know I'm stupid.

Comment: How do you run backups ?

Comment: How did you backup your files _before_ you reinstalled Ubuntu?

Comment: @waltinator I used 22.04's built in backups application using my university email due to unlimited drive space

Comment: @SorenA I meant like when you run the backups application

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].